# Performing a RegEx substitution on blocks of text in a Binary file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that contains both text and binary code.  In order for Python to process it, I have to load it as a binary file, which makes sense.

Now, the problem is, once I do that, I can't use a regular RegEx on it without some changes I don't currently understand.

I was hoping the code would be as simple the following, but it's proving not to be.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

s = open('./source.data', 'rb')
d = open('./dest.data', 'wb')

f = "REPEATED_TEXT_STRING"

c = s.read()

r = "^\d+ \d+ obj$(?:(?!^\d+ \d+ obj$)[\s\S])*?" + f + "[\s\S]+?^endobj$"

r = re.compile(r, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
t = r.sub('', c)

d.write(t)
```

I do know that r variable needs to be marked as a binary string, with a 'b' in the beginning, but it's unfortunately not as simple as that it seems for what I'm trying to do it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) states:

> Both patterns and strings to be searched can be Unicode strings as well as 8-bit strings. However, Unicode strings and 8-bit strings cannot be mixed: that is, you cannot match a Unicode string with a byte pattern or vice-versa; similarly, when asking for a substitution, the replacement string must be of the same type as both the pattern and the search string.

Which implies that if `c` is a bytes object then `r` and the substitution string must also be:

```
f = b"REPEATED_TEXT_STRING"

c = s.read()

r = b"^\d+ \d+ obj$(?:(?!^\d+ \d+ obj$)[\s\S])*?" + f + b"[\s\S]+?^endobj$"

r = re.compile(r, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
t = r.sub(b'', c)
```

I forgot about `f` and the other half of `r`. They need to be bytes also.

Comment: That would be wonderful if that was all there was to it, but I got this error in response: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Comment: Full Trace: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RegExStripper.py", line 12, in <module>
    r = b"^\d+ \d+ obj$(?:(?!^\d+ \d+ obj$)[\s\S])*?" + f + "[\s\S]+?^endobj$"
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I tried it, and unfortunately, it did not change anything.  No errors though.  I got the same MD5s on both source and destination files.  The RegEx, assuming the content was being parsed as a string, is correct.  I'm not sure if there is anything else that needs to be changed otherwise since it's binary instead.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  While the RegEx is correct for working with text, when working with binary, removing the line delimiters fixed the issue, which, since it's binary, sort of makes sense.